# How to change /dev/tty1 console font without sudo privilege from ssh?

Tags: ssh, fonts, console, fontconfig

On `/dev/tty1` display I can run and change font with:

```
setfont /etc/console-setup/cached_Uni2-TerminusBoldVGA16.psf.gz -C /dev/tty1
```

But when I run command above, from `ssh` without `sudo`: results

```
putfont: KDFONTOP: Operation not permitted
```

running with `sudo` works just fine.

I would like to run this command from ssh, or python, or shell script without `sudo`. There is a need for dynamically changing font size for my application.
And I don't want to run my-app with `sudo`, whenever I'm test running from `ssh`.

Comment: When you `ssh`, does the application actually use `/dev/tty1` of the SSH server machine? Normally a program run via `ssh` prints its output in whatever local terminal `ssh` uses, because locally it's the `ssh` process that relays data and prints anything. Then the font is a responsibility of the local console (console emulator). Please confirm you want to alter `/dev/tty1` even if it's not the terminal you're using.

Comment: Yes, I'm explicitly printing to /dev/tty1. (something like`echo 'something' > /dev/tty1`). Main output is /dev/tty1, and some minor debugging probably print to SSH.

Comment: why do you want to do this dynamically from ssh?  Why not just configure the remote machine to have the desired font and size when it boots up?   Unless you have very unusual needs or circumstances, the console font is not something that typically needs to be changed often, or over ssh.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining enough, I would like to write a program with 2 modes:
1. Normal bigger text for users, 
2. Plotting data with something like https://github.com/piccolomo/plotext
(small font: good for mode 2, bad for mode 1)
(big font: bad for mode 2, good for mode 1)